# Why is it better to use config objects in Ext.create() rather than using already defined instances?

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I have seen in multiple forum discussions that the following code should not be used.

```
let trigger = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
    fieldLabel: 'TriggerField'
});

let panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    items: [trigger],
    bbar: {
        items: [
            new Ext.form.Checkbox()
        ]
    }
});
```

Basically the forums seem to say that you should always use config objects when using Ext.create, so a better version of the code above would be:

```
let panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'TriggerField'
        }
    ],
    bbar: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'checkbox'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

My main question is why the second code is better. Can someone point to good reading material on the topic?

Comment: Can you provide an example of someone saying one is better than the other? I honestly haven't ever seen it or noticed a performance difference either way. Personally I like creating each item for readability, and it makes it easier to grab the item and manipulate it without having to do some kind of lookup assuming it's in scope. triggerField.getValue() is easier than var field= Ext.getCmp('triggerfield'); if(field){field.getValue()};. The only thing I can think is the second way maybe better for MVC/MVVM structure.

Comment: Personally - if possible - I would Ext.define a view and then create the full thing. But I guess it is more or less about company conventions.